# how to locate list elements in selenium webdriver?

Tags: list, selenium, webdriver

How to locate list elements in selenium webdriver?
 I tried using below:

driver.findElement(By.xpath(" " ));

but it is not working. Can you please suggest a solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `locate list elements in selenium webdriver`? Thanks

Comment: I am writing on program in which I login and redirect Dashboard. Now on Dashboard there are different menu list or drop-downs which have submenus. But I am unable to click on the desired menu list. I have used xpath to find element.

Comment: To click on `different menu list or drop-downs which have submenus` you have to write some code. Have you written any? Consider narrowing down your question, show us your work along with the relevant HTML please. Thanks

Comment: No I haven't written any code for it.

Comment: Below is the HTML code for element (Menu) I want to select:
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
User Account <span class="caret"></span></a> 
Below is the Sub Menu HTML code I want to select:
<a href="#" onclick="urlPostAction('N','/showUsers');">User</a>

Comment: First try to click (select) the menu. This should be your first question. Once you are able to click (select) the menu try to click (select) the sub-menu. This should be your second question.Narrow down to your particular question & feel free to raise a separate question as per your requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to loop through all the **li** elements of the **ul**. Let's say I have an unknown number of **li** elements:

Webdriver has findElements API, which can be used for this purpose..

```
List<WebElement> allListElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='...']/ul/li")); 

for (WebElement element: allListElements ) {
      System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```